# Is there still more room for more sanctions from the West against Russia?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, sanctions

Is there still more room for more sanctions from the West against Russia? The United States and the European Union have already imposed multiple rounds of sanctions on Russia in response to various issues such as the annexation of Crimea, the conflict in Ukraine, human rights concerns, cyber-attacks, and other geopolitical tensions. To me, it seems like they exhausted all the room for further sanctions, but is it still the case, is there something the U.S. could do to further sanction Russia?

Comment: How could you doubt that? Ludicrously, everyone else could refuse to allow any Russian to exit Russia…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin – but typically, term *sanctions* used in context between nations is understood as trade/economy/wealth sanctions. And also, only smaller part of world countries have joined sanctions so I am not sure how do you imagine sanctioning countries to stop Russians crossing borders to countries who are not party to any sanctions.

Comment: Until Russia is blockaded at sea, and China is blockaded for trading with Russia by land the sanctions have not gone as far as possible. Not advocating for any particular position here; just pointing out how extreme the possible is as compared to what's been done.

Comment: @miroxlav Thanks and you seem to be suggesting that because some sanctions are in place, no other sanctions could help. Is that what you meant, or what?

Comment: "they exhausted all the room for further sanctions" I don't believe one can ever exhaust all the room there. Every day new room may open up, even if it's only very small room.

Comment: **Could you please clarify?** Do you mean room for "any sanctions even when badly damaging the West" or "sanctions which will impact the Russia with minimum damages to the West"? This will make a difference in answers.

Answer (score 40):

Yes.

- There is still remaining trade between Russia and the West, and this could be banned.
- There could be "secondary sanctions" (i.e. sanctions against countries and entities which are still trading with Russia).

Both would seriously affect the economies of the West. For instance, Europe is still [importing oil and gas](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-eurostat-news/w/ddn-20230704-1) from Russia in 2023. And both the US and EU are trading with China and India, which are buying from Russia.

Comment: To add, there exist several primary areas which the West does not want to stop, e.g. Netherlands has the whole diamond-processing industry processing raw imports from Russia they repeatedly avoid to include in sanctions. Also, U. S. companies in Europe do not fall under sanctions on primary imports, for example, they are buying Russian gas for their EU plants without sanctioned restrictions. Sanctions are picked selectively, targeted mainly for areas supposed to damage Russia more than its western partners.

Answer (score 14):

The real problem is that the West is no longer the site of as much real industrial production, and is comprised much more of a rentier economy than in the past.

Large multinationals like Unilever have pointed out that their "withdrawal" from Russia would simply mean abandonment of their rights of profit. Russia would seize their factories, their machinery, their records, and their workers (and the embedded know-how those workers have) - the Western owners would not, in any real way, be able to withdraw anything, because the Russian state will step in to stop them doing so.

So whilst the West can still go further in refusing to do business with Russia, they would simply be like a customer trying to boycott a supermarket - in terms of relative strength. Or a vampire boycotting the victims, in terms of relative consequences.

Secondary action against India and China - who each have strong and long-standing affinities with Russia, and quite some shared antipathy towards Western imperialism, and are certainly helping Russia to resist the effects of sanctions imposed so far - would mean the West taking on almost the entire engine room of the world and a third of the global population at once.

The early assumption seemed to be that Russia would have already somehow folded from the existing round of sanctions - perhaps through inducing internal political instability and population exodus, if not directly due to the sanctions.

A lot of people also seemed to believe that Russia was so deeply corrupt and undemocratic that simply hitting it's oligarchs would immediately lead to Putin being purged and a Western-friendly government being quickly installed.

Yet by all informed analysis of Russian politics, the loss of Putin would not lead to a more West-friendly regime at all, but to an even more hardline regime more prepared to use nuclear weapons.

In the event nothing has occured so far on the back of sanctions. I don't think any further sanctions directly against Russia will change the situation.

We could well be seeing the very moment of the West revealed as what Mao called a "paper tiger".

Comment: Note that several countries have now abandoned the dollar as the de-facto currency for doing oil deals.

Comment: +1, I really like the pragmatism/realism vs idealism angle debated here. Ideally, the sanctions would hit Russia hard and effective, and had little-to-no effect on the countries imposing the sanctions themselves. Realistically, the sanctions hit both sides hard, but Russia was rather prepared for those blows, while the results for the West were rather painful. Pragmatically speaking, further sanctions would probably hinder the anti-Russia "coalition" more than Russia itself. TBH, imposing them was more of virtue signalling than dealing heavy one-sided economic blows.

Comment: This reads as poorly-disguised propaganda, and I'm astounded that it has upvotes on this overall-pretty-reputable site.

Comment: @RyanJensen, have you ever heard the story of the emperor with no clothes? It'd be interesting to know whether you think the boy in the story was spreading "poorly-disguised propaganda".

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm not sure what you mean by 'It's objectively true that Russia's economy is holding up well' - it's objectively true that Russia's economy has been in shambles for decades, and is doing even worse than it was a few years ago. If the argument is that they haven't completely collapsed, that's true, but total economic breakdown is neither a normal nor an intended consequence of sanctions. The fact that Ukraine has taken back a moderate amount of land is proof that intervention has been effective, because that never would have been possible if Ukraine was alone fighting Russia.

Comment: @JonathanReez but what makes it read like propaganda is the unsourced claims like 'people seemed to believe that Russia was so deeply corrupt and undemocratic that simply hitting it's oligarchs would immediately lead to Putin being purged and a Western-friendly government being quickly installed.' - no one believed this - and more egregiously, 'We could well be seeing the very moment of the West revealed as what Mao called a "paper tiger".' - Ukraine/the west are *winning* the war. More slowly and expensively than they would like, but there is no axis where Russia is currently winning.

Comment: @RyanJensen, personally I think the way Ukraine has taken back a moderate amount of land is by the provision of some of the best military hardware and by the determination of their forces - the relationship with Western sanctions seems tenuous. As for the point about "deeply corrupt and undemocratic", I can't  reference all the sludge I happen to filter through as part of ordinary daily life, but that particular sentiment is one I've heard repeatedly. It was the justification for the sanctions after all - whack the assets of the oligarchs, and they'll purge Putin, went the logic.

Comment: @Steve I agree with you on the reasons for the territory recovery - I didn't mean to imply that the *sanctions* were involved, but that the western powers were (in providing the hardware). I've also heard the statement that Russia is deeply corrupt and undemocratic (and would go so far as to say anyone who doesn't believe that statement is in denial), but I personally haven't heard anyone claim that because of that, sanctions on the oligarchs would lead to Putin's removal. It's possible that my experience is non-representative, though.

Comment: @Steve "Yet by all informed analysis of Russian politics" seems polemic; it tries to make an argument by assertion as to what is informed analysis. "by the analysis of Russian politics I find most compelling" or "As this article by Professor Jones of Indiana University points out" would be feel less poolemic.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's true that the war is far from decided. In recent months, the Ukrainians have been regaining lost territory and throughout the war their losses have been significantly lower and more sustainable (due largely to outside support). Their national will seems at least equal to Russia's, though that's hard to measure. To me, those factors are enough to describe as 'winning', though they don't prove Ukraine will achieve all their goals. As to the most likely outcome of the war, I haven't seen compelling evidence to believe your assertion (or any other specific claim).

Comment: @JonathanReez That is a clear bad-faith argument. I stated 'the outcome is far from decided, and there isn't compelling evidence to believe any specific claim' and you responded 'if you're so convinced that Ukraine would regain Crimea.' Your response does not merit further discussion.

Comment: @RyanJensen, I have to admit I also think the most likely outcome is somewhere between that Russia will retain the annexed territories with a neutrality guarantee for the rest of Ukraine from Nato, and whatever escalation is necessary to absorb or destroy the rest of Ukraine if a neutrality guarantee isn't forthcoming.

Comment: @Valorum yep, and their governments still exist, which is something we wouldn't have seen 10 years ago

Comment: @Stever "personally I think the way Ukraine has taken back a moderate amount of land is by the provision of some of the best military hardware and by the determination of their forces - the relationship with Western sanctions seems tenuous." So if a country can't defeat a major power through sanctions alone, without even sending military aid, it's a "paper tiger"? That's a bizarre standard. By that standard, what is **not** a paper tiger? Do you think Nazi Germany could have conquered Europe just by sanctioning them into submission?

Comment: @JonathanReez " if you’re not willing to make a wager then you’re not really confident in your beliefs." What beliefs are you referring to, and where did they state them?

Comment: @Acccumulation, the OP asked if there was further room for sanctions. I pointed out that Russia has only been stopped in their tracks by commitment of men and materiel. Sanctions do not appear to have altered any important factor - except perhaps to the extent that it has cut off Europe from dependence on cheap Russian energy, and forced it to buy from the US instead, possibly reducing hesitancy against war with Russia amongst German national politicians in particular.